# Convert String UUID to BigInteger in Java

Tags: java, uuid, biginteger

I am trying to convert UUID which is coming as string to Big Integer but it's failing every time with Number Format exception as it need String Decimal as parameter. Is there any way we can achieve this.

```
String x = "6CFAFD0DA976088FE05400144FFB4B37";
```

I tried with radix also but output is different.

```
BigInteger big = new BigInteger(x, 0);

System.out.println(big);
```

Any help is appreciated, TIA.

Comment: Just set the right radix, then its working

Comment: Looks like a string with hexadecimal characters. Then you should probably be using base 16.

Comment: I wonder why you process it as a `BigInteger` and not as `java.util.UUID`.

Comment: @Henry may be OP call it UUID but string value is not in that format. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are supposed to be using *radix* 16 as your string has alphanumeric values from 0-9 and A-F, set value 16 in radix as you have hexadecimal string.

```
String x = "6CFAFD0DA976088FE05400144FFB4B37";
BigInteger big = new BigInteger(x, 16);
System.out.println(big);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
144859830291446118078300087367740640055
```

Comment: Note that the radix need to be a minimum of 16 to process it, but can be as high as 36

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I agree with that.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set `radix` value to 16.

For hexadecimal String you need to define the radix value as `16`

Comment: A little more explanation would be nice.